# What is causing a folder to act hidden when it is not?

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, finder

I have a home folder that is slightly grayed out. I can't open it unless I right click on it and 'Open'.

This is `Mac OS X 10.10.2`. This folder has been troublesome and I would love to get your help to find a solution.

**Permissions are as follows:**

`drwxrwxrwx  60 root   staff   2040 14 May 14:04 sh`

I have used `Batchmod` to try and modify all the permissions and remove `ACLs` but the folder keeps acting like hidden.

Comment: Home is a hidden folder in OS X, so is grey even when you are showing invisibles. It's not the same as in nix & is only there just in case some errant nix port needs it. You should use your own 'home' folder instead, the one with your name on it, in Users, the one that comes up if you cd to ~/

Answer (score 0):

Try entering this command in Terminal:

```
chflags -v nohidden [path to homefolder]
```

You can see the full details for this command on its [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chflags.1.html)

-v provides verbose output
-nohidden is sets the target file/folder to be seen within the GUI (note: the flag is technically "hidden", but you can append "no" in front of any flag to remove it)

Comment: Ya, i tried that and it still is a greyed out folder.